# Basic concept of centripetal force - part 2

Tags: rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

Let us imagine a body is moving in a circular path. There is a centripetal force working on that object. A common (mis)intuition would be since the body is rotating in a circle, the centripetal force must be equal in all cases or else it won't be in a perfect circle. But it however isn't true since $v$ can be different in $\frac{mv^2}{r}$. Why isn't it necessary for equal centripetal force to be present for a complete circle? I beg pardon beforehand if this question is silly and absurd.

Comment: because v can change? It seems you have answered your own question. Of course, *usually* when we are talking about circular motion, v does not change.

Comment: Basic concepts of centripetal force-[part 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662149/basics-of-centripetal-force)

Comment: I don't see a question here. You are building a wrong intuition and you solve it by yourself.

Comment: "v can be different"- different from what?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are answering your own question: since the centripetal force depends on tangential velocity, the (reaction) force will change for a mass that moves at varying tangential velocity on the same geometric circle.

A typical scenario is where the mass is driven by some kind of engine, e.g. when you are driving in a car and decelerating while you are already in the (assumed perfect circle) curve. You decelerate because your intuition tells you that this will decrease the centripetal force and keep you from crashing into the fields.

What may be causing your confusion is the fact, that an otherwise (i.e. except for the circular constraint) free mass, i.e. one that has no engine and no friction and no gravity tangential to the circle, will keep its tangential velocity and hence, experience constant centripetal force.

Answer (score 1):

Like you point out yourself the centripetal force changes because the velocity does. It may seem counterintuitive since most examples of uniform circular motion $v$ remains constant. One way to understand it intuitively is to look at vertical circular motion under constant gravitational force. In this case |$v$| keeps increasing as the particle goes down and now if the centripetal force were to remain constant the particle would tend to fly away from circular trajectory. Hence, circular motion requires that the centripetal force changes with velocity.

Comment: I think you mean that |v| remains constant (the magnitude of the velocity). The velocity is a vector, and it constantly changes direction in a circular path.

Comment: In a vertical circular motion both the direction of _v_ as well as it's magnitude changes. The magnitude changes because work is being done by the gravitational force

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that velocity and forces are vectors; they have a direction. For a centripetal force, *by definition* the direction of the force is towards the center.

Now, let's assume that the velocity is orthogonal to the force. That means the acceleration will also be orthogonal to the velocity - and remember that acceleration is the (vector) derivative of velocity. Hence, the change of the velocity is orthogonal to the direction of that velocity.

So why can't the magnitude of the velocity change in a circular path? Because there's zero force and zero acceleration along the path.

For elliptical orbits, we see that the velocity changes during most of its path, just not in the apoapsis and periapsis (closest and furthest points). And that is because at those points, and only at those points, the centripetal force is orthogonal to the orbit. Comets typically follow such an elliptical path around the sun.